# Portable Repository for UWP and Desktop

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, portable-class-library

I'm trying to find an elegant solution to bridge the repository gap between an existing Windows Desktop Application and a Windows 10 Universal Application. My existing application uses a locally attached MDF file, with Entity Framework 6, but I would like to move towards a single repository that is compatible with both Desktop and Universal environments.

I have been unable to find any relevant resources on technologies that are able to provide this, and consequently I am using JSON files in environment specific factories to interact with the file system, and a shared project to hold the pre-loaded content which I have generated form the existing MDF - which is working, however it is painful to maintain and develop with UWP's API (and my understanding).

I surely cannot be the only person with this requirement/expectation; is there a standard approach to tackle this?

The bulk of my data is more or less organised into groups of key/value arrays, and typically has less than 10 tuples in each grouping, of about 2000-5000 groups, with a simple relational look-up, and is in no way performance oriented. The lower extreme quantifies the preloaded data. SQLite is looking like the best option based on the research I have done, but I am unsure how to break my repository down elegantly, without independently implementing matching structures for both environments, and copying the SQLite file I have generated externally. If SQLite is a cromulent solution, how best I structure the implementation for portability?

Answer (score 2):

Have you separated the interface and implementation of your repository? In a good design, the type of database and the details of implementation should be transparent to the data consumer (including the database type: SQL Server, SQLite and others).

If not, I suggest you separating the interface and implementation like this way:
One interface, multiple implementations

In a portable project, define the interface and domain model.

```
public interface IExampleRepository
{
    IEnumerable<string> Get();

    void Save(string value);
}
```

Implementation of Desktop (SQLite or MDF file)

```
public class UWPExampleRepository : IExampleRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Save(string value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Implementation of UWP (SQLite)

```
public class DesktopExampleRepository : IExampleRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Save(string value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Load the different implementation

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IExampleRepository repository = CreateDefaultRepository();

        var data = repository.Get();
    }

    static IExampleRepository CreateDefaultRepository()
    {
        return new DesktopExampleRepository();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have already implemented the repository pattern, but need the implementation to be consistent across both platforms. The discrete SQLite libraries aren't very helpful, but I have made great progress with EF7, with a few accommodations made for issues in beta6. It's really so I can use non-UWP libraries to seed the repository with data, which rely heavily on things that can't be ported to UWP; without implementing and maintaining two repositories for different targets with the same underlying repo technology. I will update if I have success!